# Convert Javascript Placeholder to lowercase letters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, placeholder, input-field

I am using input fields in my react website and i m displaying some placeholders in this fields.
To my amazement, this placeholders come in uppercase letters regardless of how i type it in the placeholder text.
What can i do to display this placeholder txt in lowercase letters.

Comment: add relevant tags please - your "problem" sounds like there is a style applied on like "text-transform: uppercase"; have you checked the styles with the debugger console?

Comment: Please write in correct international English, in which the word "I" is capitalized, the abbreviation for "I am" is written as "I'm", and questions end in question marks. As for your issue, it could be browser dependent--please share the results of the experiments you certainly have already done on different browsers. Or, it could be due to some UI/CSS framework you are using. How would we possibly know if you don't tell us? We are not clairvoyant. What kind of debugging have you done? By the way, it's not a "JavaScript" placeholder; JS is a language and has no placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

```
let Input = (props)=>{
    let { placeHolder, type } = props; 
    placeHolder = placeHolder.toLowerCase();

    return <input type = {type} placeholder={placeHolder}/>
}
```

I can't understand your question. But I have answserd your question with my assumption.

If your expect answer that is not, change your question to clearly.